# Compare Enum with Associated Value Short Syntax

Tags: swift, enums, swift3

I'm trying to simplify

```
var isReachable = {
    switch status {
    case .reachable: return true
    default: return false
    }
}()
```

to something like

```
var isReachable = (case status == .reachable)
```

Here is the full example:

```
enum NetworkReachabilityStatus {
    case unknown
    case notReachable
    case reachable(Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager.ConnectionType)
}

NetworkReachabilityManager().listener = { status in
    var isReachable = {
        switch status {
        case .reachable: return true
        default: return false
        }
    }()
}
```

This is only an issue when you are dealing with enums with associated values. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hardly simpler, but this is the best I could do: `var isReachable: Bool = { if case .reachable = status { return true }; return false }()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extension on NetworkReachabilityStatus can make this work.

```
extension NetworkReachabilityStatus {
    var isReachable: Bool {
        switch self {
            case .reachable(_): return true
            default: return false
        }
    }
}

NetworkReachabilityManager().listener = { status in
    var isReachable = status.isReachable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Since your full example doesn't do anything) If your motivation for this question is that you only want to perform some operation when the listener is called with "reachable" (similar to a completion being called with `success: Bool`), you can write:

```
NetworkReachabilityManager().listener = { status in
    if case .reachable(_) = status {
       // perform some operation
    }
}
```

If you wouldn't be satisfied with the readability—*Yoda condition anyone?*—you could combine it with kkoltzau's answer, which would allow you to write:

```
NetworkReachabilityManager().listener = { status in
    if status.isReachable {
       // perform some operation
    }
}
```

Comment: this was only an example, the full implementation looks different. I was just trying to ask a swift 3 related question about enums with associated values and equality.